# Parsing and looping through multi-level JSON data in Django

Tags: python, json, django

I have a Django website, and I'm making a call to Etsy's API in order to display products on the website.
The data has multiple levels (abbreviated below):

```
{
    "results":[
        {
            "title":"#020",
            "price":"5.99",
            "Images":[
                {
                    "url_570xN":"www.example.com/image1.jpg"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "title":"#051",
            "price":"5.99",
            "Images":[
                {
                    "url_570xN":"www.example.com/image2.jpg"

                }
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

I can successfully extract data from the `results` part (`title`, `price`) and display it in the template, but I can't figure out how to do the same thing for the `Images` part (`url_570xN`). I've spent a few hours trying to find the proper syntax, but I've been unsuccessful.

My `views.py`:

```
# Note: The commented lines are the ones giving me problems.
# Removing them yields no errors and displays the info I want,
# minus the images

def products(request):
    parsed_data = []
    response = requests.get('https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/shops/{SHOP_ID}/listings/active?includes=Images:1:0&api_key={KEY}')
    etsy_data = response.json()
    etsy_results = etsy_data['results']
    # etsy_images = etsy_data['results']['Images']

    for results in etsy_results:
        result_data = {}
        result_data['title'] = results['title']
        result_data['price'] = results['price']
        # for Images in etsy_images:
            # result_data['url_570xN'] = Images['url_570xN']
        parsed_data.append(result_data)

    return render(request, 'blog/products.html', {'data' : parsed_data})
```

My `products.html` template:

```
{% for result in data %}
    <p>Title: {{result.title}}
    Price: {{result.price}}
    <img src={{result.url_570xN}} width="200px"></p>
{% endfor %}
```

And lastly, the error message I get when uncommenting the lines in my `views.py`:

```
TypeError at /products/
list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT 1: Here is the complete traceback for what I have above:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/

Django Version: 2.2.4
Python Version: 3.7.4
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
 'crispy_forms',
 'django_summernote']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/Users/MeganMcCarty/Documents/coding-projects/djangogirls/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/MeganMcCarty/Documents/coding-projects/djangogirls/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/MeganMcCarty/Documents/coding-projects/djangogirls/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/MeganMcCarty/Documents/coding-projects/djangogirls/blog/views.py" in products
  21.     etsy_images = etsy_data['results']['Images']

Exception Type: TypeError at /products/
Exception Value: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

EDIT 2:
I changed my `views.py` as follows, based on Tom Carrick's answer. Everything works now, thank you so much!

```
    parsed_data = []
    response = requests.get('https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/shops/{SHOP_ID}/listings/active?includes=Images:1:0&api_key={KEY}')
    etsy_data = response.json()
    etsy_results = etsy_data['results']

    for results in etsy_results:
        result_data = {}
        result_data['title'] = results['title']
        result_data['price'] = results['price']
        result_data['url_570xN'] = results['Images'][0]['url_570xN']
        parsed_data.append(result_data)

    return render(request, 'blog/products.html', {'data' : parsed_data})
```

Comment: Can you show the whole traceback, not just the error?

Comment: @TomCarrick: I posted the whole traceback above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the images are not directly under `results`, but they are part of each item, at the same level as `title` and `price`. There can also be multiple images so I'm assuming here you just want the first one for each product.

So instead you want something like:

```py
def products(request):
    parsed_data = []
    response = requests.get('https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/shops/{SHOP_ID}/listings/active?includes=Images:1:0&api_key={KEY}')
    etsy_data = response.json()
    etsy_results = etsy_data['results']

    for results in etsy_results:
        result_data = {}
        result_data['title'] = results['title']
        result_data['price'] = results['price']
        result_data['url_570xN'] = results['Images'][0]['url_570xN']
        parsed_data.append(result_data)

    return render(request, 'blog/products.html', {'data' : parsed_data})
```

Comment: I tried this but got the same error as I did before. And you're right, there are multiple images, I just picked the one I wanted (```url_570xN```). So would I still need an index number?

Comment: Yes, you need the index because it's a list, and you always index lists with numbers. Inside the list is a dict, where you get the `url_xxx` from. Unless you showed the data wrong, the code here should be correct. I've edited the answer with the full view code, in case there's an issue there.

Comment: Hi Tom, I just figured it out, your complete views.py matches what I have. Sorry I didn't figure it out sooner based on your answer. Thank you so much for your help!